# Offsite backup to exchange

Tags: windows, email, backup, exchange

We run exchange locally on our network which is fine, until something goes bang / our local connections go down.

What options do we have to backup (i'm assuming some sort of extra mx record or similar pointing to a different server which is ready to pick up all mail, and then thread it through when the main server is back online)?

Just seeing what is out there.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is just a regular backup MX, which is quite normal to implement.

Many ISP's or webhosting companies offer this service for a low sum, but you usually have to contact them over mail/phone to get pricing/ordering, as it's usually sold as a complete hosted mail solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. If i wanted to host backup mx myself, what should I be looking for?

Comment: @TomBeech I'd just get a VPS with a fixed IP somewhere, and run Linux/FreeBSD with Postfix. But that's just a matter of taste, you gotta decide on your own what you're comfortable with. The good thing about backup mx's is that you don't do any content scanning on them, so it's basically configure-it-and-forget-it

Comment: We've got a few linux servers dotted around we can do this on, mainly centos. 

Do you setup postfix with specific settings, or literally plonk it on and add the backup mx, and it'll try and relay?

Comment: @TomBeech I set it up with settings that has to do with being a backup MX. Postfix won't just accept mail to any domain (that's called a open relay, which is NOT good). Just do some research, like googling for "postfix backup mx"

Comment: Cheers for your help mate